# Button Debounce Submit the form

Tags: angular, typescript

Create a Debounce directive, where I end up limiting the click events, or the problem you are facing is my button had the send event before ... Ex:

```
                    <button class="btn btn-light btn-block" type="submit" [hidden]="formCadastrohabilitado">
                        <i class="material-icons center align-middle ">
                            fast_forward
                        </i> INICIAR
                    </button>
```

And he with the directive was like this:

```
                    <button passeDebounceClick (debounceClick)="" [debounceTime]="500" class="btn btn-light btn-block" [hidden]="formCadastrohabilitado">
                        <i class="material-icons center align-middle ">
                            fast_forward
                        </i> INICIAR
                    </button>
```

debounce-click-directive.directive.ts:

```
    import {Directive, HostListener, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[passeDebounceClick]'
})
export class DebounceClickDirectiveDirective implements OnInit {
  @Output() debounceClick = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() debounceTime = 500;
  private clicks = new Subject();
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clicks
      .pipe(debounceTime(this.debounceTime))
      .subscribe(e => this.debounceClick.emit(e));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  clickEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.clicks.next(event);
  }
}
```

**I would just like to submit a form, but with Debounce not to double click**

Comment: What is the error? What does not work like expected?

Comment: What kind of way that is being performed is how to call a method, but that I should submit a specific form without clicking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't prevent multiple clicks with `debounceTime`, debounceTime triggers if the source observable has not emitted another value for the given duration.
What you want to achieve can be done with the [exhaustMap operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/exhaustMap).

You could add a template reference to your button:

```
<button #submitButton class="btn btn-light btn-block" type="submit" [hidden]="formCadastrohabilitado">
  <i class="material-icons center align-middle ">
      fast_forward
  </i>
  INICIAR
</button>
```

then in your component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('submitButton', {read: ElementRef, static: true}) button: ElementRef;

ngOnInit(): void {
  fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(exhaustMap((event: MouseEvent) => this.YourService.submitForm(yourData)));
}
```

While `this.YourService.submitForm(yourData)` is your services post method to submit the form data.
The `exhaustMap` operator will ignore and also not save any emissions  from the source observable until `this.YourService.submitForm(yourData)` completes.